Не могу понять как правильно произвести разборы слов
Нужен морфологический, морфемный и словообразовательный разборы следующих слов: африканец, прогуливая, прибавивший, трехтомное, издевательский, акробатический, обновлять, вечерком, лениться, самокат, содокладчик, налегке, всеобъемлющий
Сдавала уже несколько раз, без объяснений отсылают, говоря, что все неверно

Сейчас в Сети можно найти морфемный и морфологический анализ всех слов. Хуже со словообраз. анализом, сложнее найти.  Списывайте и сдавайте. Вот когда такой разбор завернут, тогда надо спрашивать на учебных ресурсах: почему неверно?

А как вы разбираете?

По схеме с одного сайта, выделяя часть речи, род, число, разбирая по составу

Выделяю основу слова, от какого произошло и способ образования с примерами

Ну пишите, посмотрим, что у вас.

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что следов собственных усилий нет. ДЗ не выполняем.


Беру любое слово: прибавивший.  Три вида разбора.

Морфемный разбор (по составу)
при/бав/и/вш/ий (бав — связанный корень: прибавить/убавить)
Морфологический разбор (часть речи)
Словообразовательный разбор
Прибави/вш/ий ← прибавить (суф. способ, формообразующий суффикс -вш-); причастная форма глагола прибавить.

Ответы можно списать, но при этом надо понимать, что списываешь. Разобраться в теме поможет учебник Литневской, где дана полная информация обо всех видах разбора.
Если будут затруднения с конкретным словом, то можно задать вопрос на форуме.


Книгу нужно использовать как справочник. Находите требуемый разбор, смотрите примеры, читаете нужный вам материал.

при(применение) - приставка, Б - корень(как в слове Б+ить, скорее всего), ав(яв) - суффикс(как в слове видавший, долю чего-то), и - суффикс(прошедшего времени), вш(вец) - суффикс(суффикс указывающий на исполнителя действия), ий - окончание. Я не сдам.

Конечно, не сдадите)) У вас диахронный поход к анализу, а нужен синхронный. Зачем вы делите корень бав на части? Каузатив к глаголу быть?  Кто сейчас  это помнит?  Уж точно не школьники.  А связанный корень могут определить все.

Кстати, как видно из истории словообразования, гнездовой способ анализа придумал совсем не Тихонов)

Да поляк придумал, на педивикии написано. Или кто?

Кто же это? Что там говорят?

Что деривационный анализ придумал поляк в 30-е годы, специально, кстати, для славянских языков.

Ага, а зачем мы старые русские грамматики тут вчера читали для слова шестъ? Там как раз описано семейство глагола верить.

А что там для слова "верить"? Кстати, этот дореформенный сборник выглядит куда более адекватнее, чем то, что пишут якобы по Тихонову на педивикии. Ну хорошо, тут пусть БАВ восходящей к Б или БА.

Так, из слога вер- образовалось громадное семейство слов: вер-а, вер-и-ть, вер-ов-а-ть, вер-и-ть-ся, вер-ов-а-ть-ся, вер-и-ти-ся, вер-ов-а-нь-е, вер-н-ый, вер-н-о, вер-н-ик, вер-н-як, вер-н-ост-ь и т.д. § 88. https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/Spravochniki/prakticheskij-uchebnik-russkoj-grammatiki-sblizhennoj-s-tserkovnoslavjanskoj-s-prilozheniem-obraztsov-grammaticheskogo-razbora/#0_30

А вер+х - х суффикс? Оно связано с верой?

Это я не знаю,  опечатка, может быть.

Не, это я спрашиваю)
